# django script causing 500 error however nothing clear in error log

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, 500-error

i'm really struggling to locate an error caused in a django script,

[here is the pastie](http://pastie.org/609963)

i had a working copy in svn, i updated some code which didn't work and when i rolled back to to the previous version it then suddenly stopped working.

i can't find anything within this script that would be causing the 500 error and nothing in the error log above provides exact details of what the error is. where and how would be the best way to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you might be trying to load an app that's not in your settings.py file. 
Which version of django are you using?

Comment: i believe i'm running 1.1 i did update via the svn but things kept breaking so i rolled it back to 1.1 surely if its an app thats not in my settings file then with the debug being true that it would pass that as an error?

Comment: On a couple occasions, I have mistakenly removed an app via svn or some silliness. If you have Debug = False in your settings file (because you're in production), then you get a stack trace like the one you posted. (I'm on 1.0 though, might be different in 1.1)